# If cell y contains any word from range x:x, mark cell y green

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, regex, concatenate

In Google Sheets, I have three columns (with different lengths!)

Column1 contains firm names (50)
Column2 containts firm names (100)

I would like to mark a cell in Column1 green (or with a number in the cell next to it) if the cell contains **any** of the names that appear in column2.

For example:

[image]

---

I tried it several times but I'm still having trouble. Here is a better example of my columns
[image: This is how the code currently works]

for column a: =REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2),LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|",1,B$2:B))) 
for column b: =REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2),LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|",1,A$2:A)))

I would like to mark/match EXAMPLE 1 with either only example 1 (1:1 match) or Example 1 firm (rather concrete match). However, the formula discoveres very different matches :-(

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- CF for **A** column:

  ```
  =REGEXMATCH(A2,TEXTJOIN("|",1,B$2:B))
  ```
- CF for **B** column:

  ```
  =REGEXMATCH(B2,TEXTJOIN("|",1,A$2:A))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Comment: thanks a lot! one more question: what is the regex for being indiffernt about the capitalisation?

Comment: @Peterthelol wrap it up into `LOWER` like: `=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2),LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|",1,B$2:B)))`

Comment: i am still struggling. :SS see response above

Comment: @Peterthelol how so?

Comment: I know this is late, but thank you user0. I was looking for this solution everywhere, & even posted a question in stackexchange because I couldn't find any similar posts.