# Google Sheets Conditional format when cell contains any word from another cell (partial text match)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, search, regex

I am currently using `=regexmatch(A1,"(?i)N02|N22|J25")` in column A to highlight the cells that contain these terms.
But I don't want to hardcode it as the search terms keep changing.
The search terms are in col. E or joint ones are in G1.

[image]

I've tried the following formulas but they don't work:

`=REGEXMATCH(A:A,G1)`

`=REGEXMATCH(A:A,TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,E2:E6))`

`=regexmatch(A:A,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,E2:E6))`

I found this formula in my search, and that person had the same issue as me. But I don't understand how I can get it to work for me.

`=if(len(A3),regexmatch(A3,"(?i)"&ArrayFormula(textjoin("|",true,trim(split($E$1,","))))),)`

Sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1911rox5wAp1eyBULCSSOWrGwQ1wFWI3sjZJPsZqjOp8/edit#gid=69482816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rules are failing because they omit the required `$` signs in the reference to the range `E2:E6`. To make it work, use a [row absolute](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/) reference, like this:

```
=regexmatch(A2, "(?i)" & textjoin("|", true, E$2:E$6))
```

See [Lance's explanation](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/60050658?msgid=60238341) of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question
`=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2),LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|",1,E$2:E$10)))`

It is from this post in StackExchange. [If cell y contains any word from range x:x, mark cell y green](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/132242/if-cell-y-contains-any-word-from-range-xx-mark-cell-y-green?rq=1)
Thanks to user0 for the answer.